# set log4j in classpath in ubunthu

Tags: java, log4j

How can I add log4j to my classpath in a maven project 
org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties"); 
gives me error

```
log4j:ERROR Could not read configuration file [log4j.properties].
java.io.FileNotFoundException: log4j.properties (No such file or directory)
```

Answer (score 1):

You generally add these properties files to `src/main/resources` folder for a maven project, and included it in the build properties in `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```